Is concatenating user-controlled input to a JNDI name unsafe?
Let's say we have some code that wants to look up DNS information about a domain. The domain is controlled by a (possibly malicious) user:
String payload = "gmail.com"; // This string is user-controlled
var env = new HashTable<String, String>();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
// some more env.put probably
var dirContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
var attributes = dirContext.getAttributes("dns:/" + payload);
// Do something with attributes

Is this unsafe? My gut tells me that JDNI is far too powerful to enter user-controlled data without any escaping (SQL injections and Log4Shell come to mind).
I couldn't find any information on possible vulnerabilities; looking through the code for the DnsContextFactory and DnsContext also makes it look like the user-controlled part is sent directly to the DNS resolver. Since the user technically can control a server that will respond to the DNS query (by hosting the nameserver), my initial thought was that someone could smuggle out information, like '$superSecretEnvVar.evil-domain.com'. But I couldn't find any information about additional processing of the string.
Is there anything unsafe about "trusting" the user input using JNDI?

Yes it is unsafe to use the rawdata since an attacker could potentially use this to execute arbitrary code on your server - CVE-2021-44228. We need to validate and sanitize Input(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(inputString)) before using in JNDI lookups

@SharadPaul Why are you suggesting HTML sanitization here?

Because in the given question payload is controlled by a user and that could potentially exploit the JNDI lookup mechanism. So this should be validated and sanitized before using it in JNDI lookups. If in the given scenario HTML sanitization doesn't work out, a custom sanitization method could be created for the specific purpose.

@SharadPaul as mentioned in the question, I'm aware of Log4Shell, but the issue depends on the user being able to inject a complete JNDI query. The question is if attacks are still possible if only parts are controlled by the user, as ldap connections won't be possible in the described scenario
